# How can I query for the meta data about a PL/SQL record type

Tags: oracle, plsql

If I have a record type like the following:

```
create or replace PACKAGE ITEM_MANAGEMENT AUTHID CURRENT_USER
as
    type item IS RECORD (
        id                         NUMBER,
        Description                VARCHAR2(30),
        Category                   VARCHAR2(30)
    );
END ITEM_MANAGEMENT;
```

From PL/SQL I can declare a record variable of this type `l_item ITEM_MANAGEMENT.Item;`

I would like to be able to query the Oracle database for the properties and their types of this record type.

For example if I want to do this for a table I would do the following:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where 1 = 1
AND OWNER = 'OWNER'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME';
```

How can I query for the meta data about an PL/SQL record type?

Answer (score 2):

That is a PL/SQL record type you seem to be talking about.  Inspecting a PL/SQL record type is only possible if the stored PL/SQL is compiled to collect PLSCOPE identifiers (otherwise, your query will get no data).

I'll post here an example of doing that.  But first let me say that I have NEVER had to do this for any production code.  What you are trying to do is not "normal", in my experience and perhaps you need to re-evaluate your approach.  Anyway, here it is.

```
-- First, tell your session that all compilations should collect
-- PLSCOPE identifiers.  If you neglect to do this, you can always ALTER 
-- a package later to recompile it with PLSCOPE identifiers as follows:
--     alter package mypackage compile 
--         plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL' reuse settings;
ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE so_test1 AS

 TYPE Item IS RECORD (
    id                         NUMBER,
    Description                VARCHAR2(30),
    Category                   VARCHAR2(30)
);

END so_test1;


-- Now, the information you want will be in DBA_IDENTIFIERS, which is 
-- stored hierarchically.  This query will print that hierarchy, starting
-- with the definition of your "ITEM" record type.     
WITH v AS (
  SELECT    Line,
            Col,
            NAME,
            TYPE,
            USAGE,
            USAGE_ID,
            USAGE_CONTEXT_ID
    FROM USER_IDENTIFIERS
      WHERE Object_Name = 'SO_TEST1'
        AND Object_Type = 'PACKAGE'
)
SELECT LPAD(' ', 2*(Level-1)) || NAME,
TYPE, USAGE, USAGE_CONTEXT_ID
  FROM v
  START WITH name = 'ITEM' and type = 'RECORD' and usage = 'DECLARATION'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR USAGE_ID = USAGE_CONTEXT_ID
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY Line, Col
/
```

Sample output:

```
+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
|     NAME      |        TYPE        |    USAGE    | USAGE_CONTEXT_ID |
+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
| ITEM          | RECORD             | DECLARATION |                1 |
|   ID          | VARIABLE           | DECLARATION |                2 |
|     NUMBER    | NUMBER DATATYPE    | REFERENCE   |                3 |
|   DESCRIPTION | VARIABLE           | DECLARATION |                2 |
|     VARCHAR2  | CHARACTER DATATYPE | REFERENCE   |                5 |
|   CATEGORY    | VARIABLE           | DECLARATION |                2 |
|     VARCHAR2  | CHARACTER DATATYPE | REFERENCE   |                7 |
+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: To explain the usefulness of this, though it isn't normal, I am writing code in another language that will call PL/SQL code and instead of hard coding the available properties for various record types in the other language I would like to dynamically generate a functions parameters given the underlying record type in PL/SQL that the functions parameters will eventually turn into.

This allows the code I am writing to be more DRY as it isn't the source of truth for what properties are available, the record type in PL/SQL is the real source of truth.

Comment: I did not mean to question your specific design.  It's just that sometimes, people come to Oracle from other platforms / languages and they try to find the "Oracle way" to do what was common on their old platform.  So, I just wanted to be clear that this is not the normal "Oracle way".  Dynamic code is hard in Oracle.  Generally speaking, tables have structure.  Cursors have structure.  And the PL/SQL programs that use them expect and depend on that structure.  That might seem a violation of the DRY principle in other languages, but its par for the course in PL/SQL (imho).